# Angular: How to use a callback function when using jsonp

Tags: angular, jsonp

I'm lost with the way I'm supposed to use a callback function when using jsonp.

I want to call an external api and I'm trying to avoid CORS issues. I read on the documentation that I had to use jsonp

```
return this.http.jsonp(myURL, 'callback').pipe(
      map(response => {
       console.log(response);
      })
    );
```

Now I don't if it's about my level of english but I dont get what to do with the 'callback' parameter which is supposedto be a callback. Can anyone provide me examples or explanations. How do I retrieve my response?

Comment: You should subscribe to get response.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **subscribe** the response.

Try like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.getResponse().subscribe( res => {
       console.log(res)
   })
}

getResponse() {
    return this.http.jsonp(myURL, 'callback').pipe(
      map(response => {
       console.log(response);
      })
    );
}
```